# Visual Studio2019 and VS Code keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a lot of Frontend development in VS Code and I am use to it's keyboard shortcuts. Now I have a new .Net project where I have to work inside VS 2019 with Resharper.

Is there a way to have the same basic keyboard shortcuts as in VS Code? I know that some will overlap, but I'm thinking on keyboard shortcuts for Comments, Save all, Move line up/down... to be the same.

Is there some plugin for this or do I have to manually change and adapt every single shortcut myself?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools`->`Options`->`Environment`->`Keyboard` and select 'Visual Studio Code' from the `Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme` drop down. You may need to remap some shortcuts manually too. It may be easier to re-learn the Visual Studio/Resharper shortcuts though.